# SQL Pivot table larger column value gives too long error

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm writing a dynamic sql pivot table query with a dataset. But when a nvarchar column value is used on the pivot, when the column value is larger than 128 it gives below error

The identifier that starts with <> is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Any workaround which can resolve this?

Comment: Without sample data and a database tag, it is pretty much impossible for anyone else to know wha tis going on.

Comment: If you are dynamically building a column name, it cannot exceed 128 characters. The problem is with the name, it is not with any particular value. You can use a sequence to generate names like col1, col2, col3... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how your tables look, some sample code and more detail would be good. 
But, just based on what you have here, you might try changing your "nvarchar" column in the original table to "float".

Like so;

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName FLOAT
```

I am using this method to pivot two values in a "VIEW" that are being used for a pie chart in a C# Windows Application. 
Hope this helps.